# How to rearrange an array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this being POSTed to my script

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [name] => test1
          [value] => test1 value
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [name] => test2
          [value] => test2 value
      )
)
```

What I want is:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [test1] => test1 value
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [test2] => test2 vlaue
      )
)
```

This is the JQuery I am using to post the data. Can someone tell me what I need to achieve this?

```
var vals = $("#post").find('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();
vals.push({
    name: 'article',
    value: CKEDITOR.instances.article.getData()
});
var qs = $.param(vals);

$.post('test.php', {
    data: vals
}, function (data) {
    if(data.success == 0) {

    }
}, 'json');
```

**EDIT:**
What I am looking to do is to simply access each key value on my server like this:

```
    echo $_POST['test1'];
...
```

Comment: So in fact this is a PHP question?

Comment: No, it's a JQuery question.

Comment: It seems easier to me to do it on the JQ side. How would I do this on the PHP side?

Comment: Hey Rocket, the vals.article... didn't work. I don't even get the editor's value using that.

Comment: I think you want `data: qs`, not `data: vals`.

Comment: `$.param` should convert the objects to a correct query string.  So, try to send that to the script instead of the array.

Comment: OK.. I'll try that now. Thanks Rocket

Comment: Hey Rocket, I'm getting a query string being sent to the server using param.

Comment: @user1709311: Is it in the format you want?

Comment: Rocket, I updated my post with what I am ultimately trying to do. Maybe that will clarify.

Comment: @user1709311: Does changing `data: vals` to `data: qs` allow you to do that or not?

Comment: You can't use a string (`test1`) as an array index - you'd need to use an object instead.

Comment: Changing `data: vals` to `data: qs` gives me a query string. Using AJAX, I remember I used to be able to access my values on the server side after I built the query string in JQuery but for some reason, it's no longer working that way and I don't understand why.

Comment: @user1709311: Yes, that gives you a query string.  Which gets POSTed to your server.  What does `console.log(qs)` print?  How about `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: @jbabey: What are you talking about?

Comment: @RocketHazmat in the question it says `Array([test1] => test1 value)`.

Comment: @jbabey: Yes it does.  What about it?

Comment: Rocket, console.log echos `&article=&access=0&date=&undefined=%3Cp%3Ehhhh%3C%2Fp%3E%0A` and var_dump gives me the same exact string.

Comment: @user1709311: Why do you have a leading `&` there?

Comment: Actually, Rocket, var_dump() shows that query string as an array, the key of that array is `data` but the string is the value.

Comment: Rocket, I cut some of the string off for brevity. It was my mistake.

Comment: @user1709311: OMG! I'm dumb.  It should be: `$.post('test.php', qs, function(){})`.  Can't believe I just noticed that >.>

Comment: There you go!!! Thank you my friend! Wanna post that and I'll credit you for the answer?

Comment: @user1709311: Just did ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `$.post`, the 2nd param is the data you want to send to the server.  It's not like `$.ajax` where you pass an object with options in it.

Try this:

```
var vals = $("#post").find('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();
vals.push({
    name: 'article',
    value: CKEDITOR.instances.article.getData()
});

$.post('test.php', vals, function (data) {
    if(data.success == 0) {
    }
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Rocket, thank you! One more question, the editor is showing on my server as undefined. Would you know why by chance?

Comment: Happy New Year!  Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it looks like your 'name' property is constant and equal to 'article'.  If, however, article is actually a variable defined earlier in your code, then this should work:

```
var vals = $("#post").find('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();
var newVal = {};
newVal[article] = CKEDITOR.instances.article.getData();
vals.push(newVal);
```

Comment: Let me ask you ic3, would it be better to parse this query string serverside instead of trying to do it this way?

Comment: no, you'll be transferring less information if you pre-process in JS.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was explaining to Rocket above that when I used AJAX a while back that when I would build the query string that I would be able to immediately access the key/value pair on the server but for some reason, it's not working that way any longer and I'd like to know why that is. Should I be using AJAX instead?

Comment: @user1709311: You *are* using AJAX.

Comment: I'm showing my ignorance, I know... :)  There is something really different about using `.post` than `$ajax`. I can no longer access the query string as POST vars.